# Next.js doesn't recognize new files in the .next build folder

Tags: next.js

I know there are other solutions to this issue, but I want to understand why Next.js, after building the project in the default folder .next where static files are stored and can be accessed when needed, doesn't recognize the new files I upload. I have implemented a write function in my API to create a file in this folder, and I delete it after 2-3 seconds. However, the changes are not reflected in real-time. Even though the file is created, I can't find it until I restart the server. How can I make it available in the runtime?